# How to print out the values with count in dictionary using Counter

Tags: python, dictionary

My code is below

```
def tuptodi(tup, dictio): 
    for a, b in tup: 
        dictio.setdefault(a, []).append(b) 
    return dictio
tups = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value1'),('key3', 'value3'),('key1', 'value1'),('key1', 'value2')]
dictionary = {} 
print (tuptodi(tups, dictionary))
```

My Out

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value1', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value1'], 'key3': ['value3']}
```

My desired Out

```
{'key1':{'value1':2},
{'key2':{'value1':1},
{'key3':{'value3':1}
```

How to achieve this by `from collections import Counter`

Comment: So what about value2 ?

Comment: Maybe this is an error, but for the key1 the values should be: {'key1':{'value1':2, 'value2':1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` and `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

tups = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value1'),('key3', 'value3'),('key1', 'value1'),('key1', 'value2')]
cnt = defaultdict(Counter)

for i,j in tups:
    cnt[i].update([j])

cnt
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'key1': Counter({'value1': 2, 'value2': 1}),
             'key2': Counter({'value1': 1}),
             'key3': Counter({'value3': 1})})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` in a dict comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

data = {'key1': ['value1', 'value1', 'value2'], 'key2': ['value1'], 'key3': ['value3']}
out  = {key: Counter(sublist) for key, sublist in data.items()}

print(out)
# {'key1': Counter({'value1': 2, 'value2': 1}), 
#  'key2': Counter({'value1': 1}), 
#  'key3': Counter({'value3': 1})}
```